# Numpy RuntimeError with Bitcoin Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, neural-network

I am getting an unexpected Runtime error by numpy whilst using data pulled straight from BitcoinCharts' ajax requests for an RNN I am trying to make. This issue began after I changed the date range to pull the data from.

Here is the error information:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- 
packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:36: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in 
reduce
return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial)
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- 
packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:36: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in 
reduce
```

return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial)

Here is my code:

```
url = 'http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/chart.json?m=itbitUSD#rg360zig12- 
       hourztgSzm1g10zm2g25zv'
data = json.loads(requests.get(url).content)

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 
                               'volume_btc', 'volume_curr', 'weighted_price'])

df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)


scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
close=scaler.fit_transform(df['close'].values.reshape(len(df['close']), 1))
```

The data's shape is (1889, 7)
I have also tried:

```
close=scaler.fit_transform(df['close'].values.T.tolist())
```

but it hasn't made any difference.

If it makes any difference I am using Jupyter Notebooks (.ipynb)

Also when trying to plot that data I get this warning:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

or the data appears broken

Comment: Think yourself lucky you got an overflow error, a lot of overflows are silent in numpy

Comment: Is that the full traceback? Please can you edit the traceback as code (`{}` button in editor) rather than a quote?

Comment: @roganjosh It's just a warning, not an error, so there is no trace.

Comment: @roganshosh Yes, that is the full traceback error I received in jupyter notebook. I have made the traceback as code as well.

Comment: @Alfe aren't they equivalent for numpy? I thought they displayed like warnings due to how it propagates back up from C. They still terminate execution?

Comment: No, it's just a warning.  Execution continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to sum up a lot of values (using `reduce` via `umr_sum` via something in your code I couldn't spot) and in the process reach the limit of the data type you are using.

You should be fine after converting all your data from some integer type (`int32` or similar, that's the type the data comes in) to a float type or a larger integer type (e. g. `int64`).  Summing up the same values then will not lead to an overflow anymore.

First, find out which of your statements produces this warning (e. g. by adding `print` statements between each two statements).  Then cast the numbers to a data type with a higher range than the original.